# what is the difference between setting a files src in html vs javascript

Tags: javascript, html, view

Quick version:

if i make a div, and put an image in it it works just fine.

```
this 
<img id="main_image"; src="~/images/tea_offer.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%" /> 
gives 
localhost/images/tea_offer.jpg
```

but then i try to change the image with javascript

```
this
document.getElementById("main_image").src = "images/cake.jpg"
gives
localhost/home/~/images/cake.jpg
```

and the image just doesn't work.   i think this ====> localhost/home/~/images/cake.jpg. is wrong.
please help.

Long version.

i have a simple website, it has a background image and a blue box. the background image changes when you click on the blue box. images are stored locally in wwwroot. 
when the blue box is clicked the background image simply goes white and my computer is unable to find the image it is looking for.

[proof the images are stored in propper place with propper name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs8Wu.jpg)

How can i get the javascript to find an image like html does?

Comment: _"the image just doesn't work"_ - Because there's no server that would translate the `~` into the actual path.

Comment: but the image is local. and if i dont use ~/   i still start with /home after localhost which makes it impossible to add stuff to get to wwwroot

Comment: you can use `../` to move up one folder instead, try with relative paths if absolutes are not working for you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding "~" to your path in javascript version, use "/" so it be "/images/cake.jpg", to query from root.

More info: https://coderwall.com/p/8nhqeg/relative-paths-from-the-root-in-javascript

Updated Info:

- You need to provide absolute link to you image (which would vary from DEV env where it is probably localhost:80, against published Prod env http:....com/). So it would be best idea to have the BASE_URL in a static variable, and prepend it to all the calls to your images.

Comment: Why do you think that `~` is always the root?

Comment: is the relative root which in case of published website it would be http://.....com/
Although, now I'm not 100% sure.. I check that out